# How to get the joining date of a user in Super Group Chat using Telegram Bot API? PHP

Tags: php, api, bots, telegram, php-telegram-bot

I'm trying to make a bot which can clear spam messages. The logic I'm using is by age of user if the user is not in the group for more than 10 days then it cant post any external links or forwarded messages.
For that, I need **joining date of a user in Super Group Chat** using Telegram Bot API?

Answer (score 2):

There is no particular parameter given by Telegram Bot API but, when some member joins the Telegram group get this date saved in the database. By (current date - joining date) you can get the number of days, for how long this user is the member of a group.